# I don't understand a macro of inet/netinet/in.h

Tags: c, macros

I'm working with IPv6 migration of software drivers in C and I want to understand the following macro of **IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT** and **IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT**. Please help:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifndef        _NETINET_IN_H
#define        _NETINET_IN_H        1
#include <features.h>
#include <bits/stdint-uintn.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bits/types.h>

.
.
.

#define IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } } }
#define IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }
```

Comment: It is probably used as an initializer for some array or structure. Just replace the occurrences of the macro name with it's body.

Comment: You can grep the source tree for uses of those macros in `.c` or other `.h` files.  (I usually use `find`, `xargs`, and `grep`, but I think grep also has an `-R` option to recursively grep subdirectories.)

Comment: It's a 16 byte / 128 bit initializer for the "any" + "loopback" address. The 32bit IPv4 equivalent is `#define INADDR_ANY ((unsigned long int) 0x00000000)` + `#define INPORT_ANY 0`

Comment: The `_INIT` portion of the macro identifiers is a strong signal about their intended usage: they are meant to be used as *initializers*.  Moreover, their specific syntactic form has no other use in C. In particular, they are initializers suitable for objects of type `struct in6_addr` (which is also strongly clued by their identifiers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are initializers for `struct in6_addr`. The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html) requires `struct in6_addr` to have at least the single member `s6_addr`, which must be a `uint8_t[16]`.

Most of the time, `struct in6_addr` is, however, implemented as a nested union containing 8, 16 and 32-bit integers arrays for optimized access. For example, glibc has

```
struct in6_addr {
  union {
    uint8_t __u6_addr8[16];
    uint16_t __u6_addr16[8];
    uint32_t __u6_addr32[4];
  } __in6_u;
};
```

and an accessor define

```
#define s6_addr                 __in6_u.__u6_addr8
```

Remember, that union initializers need their own set of curly brackets and operate on the first member of the union. The outermost `{}` are required for the struct, the next level of `{}` for the union and the innermost `{}` for the array initializer.

Hence

```
#define IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } } }
```

which is

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

and

```
#define IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }
```

which is

```
::1
```

Answer (score 1):

[The man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) explains well.

> To bind an `AF_INET6` socket to any process, the local address should
>   be copied from the `in6addr_any` variable which has `in6_addr` type. 
>   In static initializations, **`IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`** may also be used,
>   which expands to a constant expression.  Both of them are in network
>   byte order. The IPv6 loopback address `(::1)` is available in the
>   global `in6addr_loopback` variable.  For initializations,
>   **`IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT`** should be used. IPv4 connections can be handled with the v6 API by using the v4-mapped-on-v6 address type;
>   thus a program needs to support only this API type to support both
>   protocols.  This is handled transparently by the address handling
>   functions in the C library.